# How to group exact Tandem values from 2 column of table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with 2 column `latitude` and `longitude`.
some of data rows have exact match tandem values on 2 columns  .

```
/* Points Table */
lat |long
2.1 |5.8
2.1 |5.6    -Set as Group
2.1 |5.6    -Set as Group
2.1 |5.6    -Set as Group
2.3 |5.2
2.4 |5.3
2.5 |5.3    -Set as Group
2.5 |5.3    -Set as Group
2.6 |5.3
2.5 |5.3
```

I want to set as Group tandem values of 2 columns , for example the result of my SQL Query Like :

```
/* Points Table */
lat |long
2.1 |5.8
2.1 |5.6    -Grouped
2.3 |5.2
2.4 |5.3
2.5 |5.3    -Grouped
2.6 |5.3
2.5 |5.3
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I forget to say have problem with group by , values have more than one time tandem , for example on my edit : now we have two time `2.1 & 5.6` value , now we can't use just `GROUP BY` , please test with : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d196 .

Comment: PLEASE always be clear while asking the question. And don't change the question this may make the answer invalid.

Comment: @hims056 sorry , that's missing on first, now have a easily way to do it ? or I must create a new question ?

Comment: I think you should ask another question and rollback this question otherwise this will make all of 3 answers invalid. And by asking new question you can get more response. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword to remove duplicate record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `lat`, `long` FROM MyTable;
```

Alternatively you can group them by [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause like this:

```
SELECT `lat`, `long`
FROM MyTable GROUP BY `lat`, `long`;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f94e/5)

Comment: @Dear Downvoter, Can you please explain the reason behind downvote?

Comment: see first post , something missing on first . I want to Group just tandem values .

Answer (score 0):

You can group it in mysql:

```
SELECT lat, long FROM your_table GROUP BY lat, long;
```

Also you can avoid equal values in the future by adding index to these 2 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX(lat, long);
```

Comment: see first post , something missing on first . I want to Group just tandem values .